# Notation for this quaternary linear code

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, information-theory, coding-theory

I've been reading about self dual codes, and the literature says that there is a quaternary self dual code $$i_2 \otimes \mathbb{F}_4$$where $i_2 = {\{00,11}\}$ is a binary self dual code and $\mathbb{F}_4$ is the field of four elements.

This code has weight enumerator $x^2 + 3y^2$, and so only has $4$ codewords.

What is this code? What does $i_2 \otimes \mathbb{F}_4$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: View $i_2$ as ${\Bbb F}_2$-space of dimension $1$, basis $\{11\}$, and ${\Bbb F}_4$ as ${\Bbb F}_2$-vector space of dimension $2$, basis $\{1,\alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ is a zero of the irreducible polynomial $x^2+x+1$. In this way, the tensor product $i_2\otimes_{{\Bbb F}_2} {\Bbb F}_4$ is well-defined and has dimension $2$ (as the product of dimensions).

Comment: So $i_2 \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_2} \mathbb{F}_4$ has basis ${\{(11) \otimes 1, (11) \otimes \alpha}\}$? How does $ (11) \otimes 1$ even make sense?